# How to find the mean and variance of a poisson inverse Gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions

I'll like to to know how to calculate the mean and variance of the above distribution or probably a material that I can get to download on it which gives explicit detail.
the Understanding of this will really help me in my thesis

Comment: Yes,the case whereby the parameter is drawn from inverse Gaussian distribution

Comment: You really should specify the functional form you are using ... there are many alternative ways of defining the distributions.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to compute these is to use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

$\text{E}(X) = \text{E}_\Theta( \text{E}_{X} ( X | \Theta))$

$\text{Var}(X)=\text{E}[\text{Var}(X |\Theta)]+\text{Var}[\text{E}(X |\Theta)]$

where here $\Theta$ will be the parameter of the Poisson, so $X|\Theta \sim \text{Pois}(\Theta)$. Because it's Poisson, all the inner (conditional) expectations and variances simply yield the Poisson parameter.

The rest is simply a matter of substitution of the mean and variance of the inverse Gaussian.